# Is it possible to import my xbox live profile to the xbox windows 10 app?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-app

I have copied my xbox profile to a USB stick before selling my xbox 360.
And now the the xbox app on Windows 10 is out I want to import my profile to this app in order to make it living again.

Does anybody know if it is possible?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
The problem is that I have played with this profile offline and I want to get all achievements I've won. The xbox 360 used can't be connected to internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have copied Xbox 360 **only** files to your USB.  These are only compatible with Xbox 360 consoles.

If your account is live enabled, in that you registered and synced your account online, then all you need to do is use your login details in Windows 10.  Your profile will be downloaded from the Xbox servers.  This profile will be the profile that was last synced.

Both gold and "silver" free accounts will have their profiles synced throughout the time the Xbox 360 was connected to the internet.

This is the same for Games for Windows, Xbox One and the various mobile platforms.

Comment: The problem is that I have played with this profile offline and I want to get all achievements I've won. The xbox 360 used can't be connected to internet.

Comment: Xbox doesn't currently offer that functionality.  Anything done offline must be synced online in order to persist. In your situation I would suggest getting a friend or family member to help upload and sync your profile.

Comment: Alternatively, lose the achievements you have earned and look to re-earn them at a later date.  If you kept the saves for the games too then this would speed up the process.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to sync my profile with my cousin xbox 360.

Comment: Just convert your offline account to a silver xbox live account. You won't lose your achievements by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The USB is formatted for xbox, and as such, can not be directly interpreted by the computer to transfer your data. However, you can still transfer using another Xbox 360.

Connect the USB to a friends Xbox, and log your profile into Xbox Live. Doing so will update your achievements to your online profile.

Simply log into Windows 10 with the same login details you use for your Xbox, and you will be linked to the same account. Windows 10 uses the exact same Xbox account, so will synchronise your player info, achievements and games, among other things.